# SQL select all day from parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select all day from 1 parameter, e.g.: I click on any date for May, e.g.: '2018-05-20'. Then, it will return all day in May (1-31). Can it be done in a MySQL query?

**P/S:** I'm using this for Jaspersoft iReport 5.6.

My query at the moment requires 2 parameters:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
  sample
WHERE
  Date >= (Parameter start date) AND Date <= (Parameter end date)
```

Comment: Have a look at the function MONTH() - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Query will result in all days form your table with respect to the selected date which you pointed "2018-05-20". That mean all the dates in your table on May 2018. Hope this will address your query

```
 SELECT datecolumnName
    FROM sample -- <your tablename> 
    WHERE YEAR(datecolumnName) = YEAR('2018-05-20') AND 
          MONTH(datecolumnName) = MONTH('2018-05-20');
```

You can check further Date time functions from here [MySQL Date time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE Month(Date) = Month(Parameter start date) And Year(Date) = Year(Parameter start date);
```